# php declaring application root

Tags: php

I have a little problem: I began a project as a subdirectory in a larger web project. Thus the web file path is something like /../myProject. But things have progressed and I've realized that this should be its own project. However, I'd like to be able to keep it where it (as a sub-directory) also make it a sub-domain wherein `myProject` becomes the root. (There is also the possibility that my project will be mirrored at a library site, where it will once be in a sub-directory).

The problem I having with all this is that in some cases I have `html_partial files`, (for instance for the header or footer). But the relative path of these partials differs depending on where you are in the file tree. I originally solved this by always going back to the root.

But now, you see, depending on where my project lives, the root will be different. What I'd like to do is declare myProject as the "application root" and then be able to use relative paths based on this `application` root rather the than the `web root'. This way, all of the relative paths within 'myProject' will work no matter where`myProject` lives in the web path.

Does PHP have a way to declare something like an `Application Root` if so, can you explain it me or direct me to its documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do something lile this in the front controller:

```
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(__DIR__));
```

Then you can do things like:

```
set_include_path(APPLICATION_PATH . '/include');
```

Or:

```
$fp = fopen(APPLICATION_PATH . '/path/to/some/file', 'r');
```

If your app doesn't make use of a front controller, you could define an environment variable in your vhost config or .htaccess:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_PATH /full/path/to/my/app
```

And then use:

```
getenv('APPLICATION_PATH')
```

Comment: is 'front controller' a technical term for something or just a file i create in the application root (as suggested in the answer above). I never run into that concept before.

Comment: A front controller is a design pattern where you have one single file (e.g., index.php) that every request flows through. In this case, it's easy to add processing that fires for every request. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern

Answer (score 1):

You could simply have a PHP file in your application root directory which would define the directory it is in as the application root. The file could be as simple as this:

```
<?php
define('APPLICATION_ROOT', __DIR__);
?>
```

You could then include this file as needed and base all of your file paths off of `APPLICATION_ROOT`. Note that `APPLICATION_ROOT` would not have a trailing slash as defined here (unless your file happened to be on in the machines root directory, which is unlikely).

Comment: forgive for my ignorance but what would the file path look like when written? `APPLICATION_ROOT/html_partials/header.php`?

Comment: If you were doing an include or something it might look like `include(APPLICATION_ROOT . '/html_partials/header.php')`